# Query utilizing JPQL does not work as nativeQuery

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I have the following sql query which works as expected

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("" +
                "SELECT d.id FROM document d \n" +
                "INNER JOIN users_documents ud \n" +
                "ON ud.document_id = d.id\n" +
                "WHERE ( d.document_state_id=2 OR d.document_state_id=3 OR d.document_state_id=1)\n" +
                "AND d.title LIKE \"%abc%\" AND ud.user_id=4 AND ud.sharing_type_id=1\n" +
                "OR (d.document_state_id=1 AND d.title LIKE \"%abc%\" AND ud.user_id=4 AND ud.sharing_type_id=2);");
```

And I have this JPQL which DOES not work, it returns nothing always.

```
   TypedQuery<Long> q1 = entityManager.createQuery("Select d.id FROM Document d " +
                    "INNER JOIN d.documentsForUsers ud" +
                    " WHERE ((d.documentState.id=2 OR d.documentState.id=3 OR d.documentState.id=1)" +
                    " AND (d.title LIKE :value2 AND ud.user.id=:id AND ud.sharingType.id=2))" +
                    " OR (d.documentState.id=1 AND d.title LIKE :value3 AND ud.user.id=:id2 AND ud.sharingType.id=2)"
            , Long.class);



    q1.setParameter("value2", "%"+name+"%");
    q1.setParameter("id", userId);
    q1.setParameter("value3", "%"+name+"%");
    q1.setParameter("id2", userId);
```

How can I rewrite that nativeSQL query to JPQL to make it work properly?

Comment: If you completely remove the `WHERE` clause from the JPQL query, do you get any results back?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen yes, that works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer mainly corrects some parentheses typos, but appreciate that your `WHERE` clause in the JPQL query is not the same as in the native.  Applying the same balancing of parentheses to the JPQL query gives:

```
String sql = "SELECT d.id FROM Document d INNER JOIN d.documentsForUsers ud " +
    "WHERE d.document_state_id IN (1,2,3) AND " +
    "d.title LIKE :value2 AND ud.user_id = :id AND ud.sharing_type_id = 1 OR " +
    "(d.document_state_id = 1 AND d.title LIKE :value3 AND ud.user_id = :id2 AND ud.sharing_type_id = 2)";
```

I don't know exactly what logic you are trying to use in the `WHERE` clause, but the above at least stays true to what is being used in the native query.

I *suspect* that you might be intending this version:

```
String sql = "SELECT d.id FROM Document d INNER JOIN d.documentsForUsers ud " +
    "WHERE (d.document_state_id IN (1,2,3) AND " +
    "d.title LIKE :value2 AND ud.user_id = :id AND ud.sharing_type_id = 1) OR " +
    "(d.document_state_id = 1 AND d.title LIKE :value3 AND ud.user_id = :id2 AND ud.sharing_type_id = 2)";
```